# Вывод глобальной переменной SESSION PHP

Tags: php

Имеется страница авторизации, в коде есть проверка на логин, пароль, если логин или пароль неверны - выводится ошибка из $_SESSION['error_msg'] = 'Неверный логин или пароль!'; Как сделать так, чтобы эту переменную можно было вывести после кнопки "Войти"?

```
<?php
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<p class="p-error">'.$_SESSION['error_msg'] .'</p>'; 
if(!empty($_SESSION['error_msg'])){
 unset($_SESSION['error_msg']);
}

if($_SESSION['admin']) {
   header('Location: ../admin/admin-panel.php');
}

require_once '../components/db.php';
?>

<?php
          
               if(!empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
               
               $login = $_POST['login'];
               $password = md5($_POST['password']);
               $count = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password' ");
               if (mysqli_num_rows($count) == 0 )
               {
                  $_SESSION['error_msg'] = 'Неверный логин или пароль!';
               header('Location: ../admin/auth.php');
                           
               } else {
               header("Location: ../admin/admin-panel.php");
               echo "<br/>Да<br/>";

               $_SESSION['admin'] = [
                  "id" => $admin['id'],
                  "name" => $admin['name']
               ];
               echo mysqli_num_rows($count);
               
               }
               }
?>
<body>

   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
         <?php include '../pages/header.php'; ?>

         <div class="section-admin-panel animate__animated animate__backInDown">
            <div class="container">
               <h1 class="h1-panel">Авторизация в админ-панель</h1>

               <div class="form__block">
                  <form action="" method="POST" class="form">
                     <input type="login" name="login" placeholder="Введите логин" required><br>
                     <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" class="input-top" required><br>

                     <button type="submit" class="btn-auth"><span>Войти</span></button>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Уберите строчку кода:

```
echo '<p class="p-error">'.$_SESSION['error_msg'] .'</p>';
```

и добавьте перед закрывающим тэгом </form> строчку кода:

```
<p class="p-error"><?= $_SESSION['error_msg']; ?></p>
```

Comment: А знак `=` после `<?` разве нужен?

Comment: <?= это короткая запись <?php echo https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php